# Autohotkey Transparent PNG on Aero Window

Tags: png, transparency, gdi+, autohotkey, aero

I want to create something similar to [Winlaunch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winlaunch/) which is an app that shows an Aero window with Program shortcuts. Up to now I was able to create the window with Aero.ahk Library and Autohotkey GUI. But PNG icons with transparency show an ugly white border around them. See screenshot.

[image]

**How to fix ?**

This is the script so far:

```
#Include AeroLib.ahk
#Include Gdip.ahk
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, mx, my
mx := mx-250
my := my-150
Aero_StartUp()

DWM_Win_TransColor:=0x123456
Gui,Color,%DWM_Win_TransColor%
Gui 1: +AlwaysOnTop
Gui,+LastFound
MainHandle:=WinExist()

Aero_ChangeFrameAreaAll(MainHandle)
Gui Add, Picture, x10 y10 w96 h96 gRunProgram1, ie.png
Gui 1: Show,x0 y0 w320 h240,Launchy
WinSet,TransColor,%DWM_Win_TransColor%,ahk_id %MainHandle%
Return

RunProgram1:
Run C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
goto GuiClose

GuiClose:
Aero_End() ;Shutdown Aero Libary
Gdip_Shutdown(pToken)
ExitApp
```

I also tried GDIp Library which seems to be able to render PNG without the artifacts, but I dunno how to combine both.

Comment: have you tried with `AltSubmit` ?

Comment: Yes. It improves a little but i dont get rid of the artifacts completely. Guess Ill have to accept it as it is

Comment: Are you positive that the png itself doesn't have a white border? Also, have you tried to use other transparent image types (like GIF, TARGA, TIFF, and maybe ICO)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kinda late, but I managed to use the GDIP library to render PNG without aliasing, an example before and after:
[image]

Before trying the code you need to have a folder called "lib" in the same directory as your script, and inside the "lib" folder you should have a file named "Gdip.ahk" and contains the following code:
https://github.com/tariqporter/Gdip/blob/master/Gdip.ahk

Now you can try this code:

```
If !pToken := Gdip_Startup()
{
    MsgBox, 48, gdiplus error!, Gdiplus failed to start. Please ensure you have gdiplus on your system
    ExitApp
}
frameNum1 := Gdip_CreateBitmapFromFile("6.png") 
Gui, 2: -Caption +E0x80000 +LastFound +OwnDialogs +Owner +AlwaysOnTop
Gui, 2: Show, NA
hwnd1 := WinExist()
Width := Gdip_GetImageWidth(frameNum1), Height := Gdip_GetImageHeight(frameNum1)
hbm := CreateDIBSection(Width, Height)
hdc := CreateCompatibleDC()
obm := SelectObject(hdc, hbm)
G := Gdip_GraphicsFromHDC(hdc)
Gdip_SetInterpolationMode(G, 7)
trans := 1
Gdip_DrawImage(G, frameNum1 , 0, 0, Width, Height, 0, 0, Width, Height, trans)
UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd1, hdc, 200, 600, Width, Height)
```

[image]